# OncollisionEnter2D not working but OnTriggerEnter2D works fine

Tags: unity-game-engine, 2d, unityscript

I am newbie in Unity & here I am trying to fire  `OncollisionEnter2D`

I have `Is Kinematic` turned Off, for the object & its calling `beeCollision.js` script

If i play in Unity-editor, i can see- its colliding & forcing the Collided-object to rotate /move. So its definitely colliding, but somehow the `OncollisionEnter2D` is not getting called.

However, if I put `Is Trigger` on, the `OnTriggerEnter2D` works just fine.

Here is the *beeCollision.js* script-

```
function OncollisionEnter2D (other: Collision2D) {
    // NOT GETTING CALLED
    Debug.Log("collided 1");
}

function OnTriggerEnter2D(other : Collider2D) {
    // Works well, if Is Trigger is turned on
    Debug.Log("collided 2");
}
```

& here are 2 screenshots of Unity editor-

1. Settings for the Player:

[image]

2. Settings for the Obstacles prefabs:

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check this url,
http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/30_search.html?q=OnCollisionEnter2D

Change "OncollisionEnter2D" to "OnCollisionEnter2D", It will work for you.

Answer (score 1):

also make sure that is OnCollisionEnter2D 
b/c i was struggling with that for almost two hour and i figured out that i missed an i in Collision.